# Events in gnome calendar spanning two days in notification center

Tags: gnome, notification, evolution, calendar, gnome-calendar

I use gnome calendar on daily basis. But for some reason now a single event is lasting for 2 days instead of one. I'm on Ubuntu 21.04. I don't think this bug existed when I was on 20.10.

In the gnome calendar app, it shows that the event is a day long but whenever I open the calendar in the notification center it instead shows the same event lasting for two days instead of one.

I'm attaching some screenshot to further demonstrate this issue.

As you can I see I have a event on 6th July which lasts a single day in the gnome calendar app.
[image: Gnome Calendar Screenshot]

But the same event lasts 2 days long when viewed in the notification center calendar.
[image: Notification Center Screenshot]

[image: Notification Center Screenshot]

This is a really annoying bug and I was wondering if there is any way to fix this issue.

Any help is appreciated!